# Why do I get a type error when trying to run convolutional neural network on pycharm, with python

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I've been trying to build a neural network model that will be able to classify images. But there is this one consistent error that keeps on popping up. Can anyone please help me with this? Here are the code and error below:
[Second Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxEmM.png)[third Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brCCx.png)

```
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,img_size])
y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,no_classes])
#keep_probable=tf.argmax(y,dimension=1)
keep_probable=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

def conv2d(x,w,b,strides=1):
    x=tf.nn.conv2d(x,w, strides=[1,strides,strides,1],padding='SAME')
    x=tf.nn.bias_add(x,b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)

def maxpool2d(x,k=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x,ksize=[1,k,k,1],strides=[1,k,k,1],padding='SAME')

def conv_net(x,weights,biases,drop_out):
    x=tf.reshape(x,shape=[-1,50,50,1])

    conv1=conv2d(x,weights['wc1'],biases['bc1'])
    conv1=maxpool2d(conv1,k=2)

    conv2=conv2d(conv1,weights['wc2'],biases['bc2'])
    conv2=maxpool2d(conv2,k=2)

    fcl=tf.reshape(conv2,[-1,weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fcl=tf.add(tf.matmul(fcl,weights['wd1'])[][2],biases['bd1'])
    fcl=tf.nn.relu(fcl)

    # application of dropout
    fcl.tf.nn.dropout(fcl,dropout)
    # output of the class prediction
    out=tf.add(tf.matmul(fcl,weights['out']),biases['out'])

    return out

weights = {

'wc1': tf.Variable((tf.random_normal)([5,5,1,32])),
'wc2': tf.Variable((tf.random_normal)([5,5,32,64])),
'wd1': tf.Variable((tf.random_normal)([7*7*64,1024])),
'out': tf.Variable((tf.random_normal)([1024,no_classes]))

}

biases = {

'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([no_classes]))

 }

# construction of a model
pred = conv_net(x,weights,biases,keep_probable)

# definition of the loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred,labels =y))
optimiser = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate=LR).minimize(cost)

# Evaluating the model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred,tf.float32))
```

Following is the error I get:

`TypeError: Expected bool for argument 'transpose_a' not <tf.Variable 'Variable_6:0' shape=(1024,) dtype=float32_ref>.`

Comment: Without seeing the full traceback (the error message) or the code it's hard to understand the problem, could you edit your question with that information please?

Comment: @LuRst Thanks for the reply, here is the code

Comment: @LuRst please see the code above

Comment: Please give the full error traceback not just the final error.

Comment: @mnis I've attached the traceback snippet above,Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your line

```
fcl = tf.add(tf.matmul(fcl, weights['wd1'], biases['bd1']))
```

You are missing a bracket. Do this:

```
fcl = tf.add(tf.matmul(fcl, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
```

Comment: Thanks Man, really appreciate this because the error got solved but another one popped up and this is starting to get on my nerves, so do you mind helping me with this as well :

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/bangol/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/scratch_4.py", line 108, in <module>
    pred = conv_net(x,weights,biases,keep_probable)
  File "C:/Users/bangol/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/scratch_4.py", line 90, in conv_net
    fcl.tf.nn.dropout(fcl,dropout)
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'tf'

Comment: do `fcl = tf.nn.dropout(fcl,dropout)` instead of `fcl.tf.nn.dropout(fcl,dropout)`

Comment: Snap, this brought the old error message...What can I do now?

Comment: Because the line `out=tf.add(tf.matmul(fcl,weights['out'],biases['out']))` has the same problem as beofore. It's missing a bracket

Comment: Done: There's still more errors.Please bare with me, I've only started a month back learning deep learning and it's proving to be a huge challenge alone.

Comment: I'll attach the traceback above

Comment: Your second traceback has same problem again. It's missing a bracket in line 86. you did not add the bracket as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Ok Done, its giving me this now, please see the third traceback above

Comment: `tf.initialise_variables()` expects an argument which is the list of variables you want to initialize. If you want to initialize all of them in one go then use `tf.global_variables_initializer()` instead of that.

Comment: am getting this now:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/bangol/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/scratch_4.py", line 125, in <module>
    X,Y=Train_dir.train.next_batch(batch_size)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'train'

Comment: to get the next batch, usage is `dataset.train.next_batch` not `train_directory.train.next_batch`. You will have to learn the proper usage of `dataset` API before proceeding further as it's not possible to explain everything here.

Comment: OK thanks, Do you have anyone you can recommend on youtube were I could learn how to do this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any as of now because I myself has not explored it much. Maybe you can try the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks For your time and pointing me in the right direction Man, really appreciate it.